# Streetview in Android Google API 11

Tags: android

Streetview as such referes to the panoramic view of an address on Google maps. But in Android Google API, in the native map, streetview doesn't yield any change when set to true. In Stack Overflow, it has been answered as a deprecated function.
Does anyone know where Google / Android has mentioned about this?
Can we get panoramic picture view by using Google API 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StreetView in Android Google 11 is not the same like panoramic streetview in Google Maps api. if you are not using the Javascript API and are instead working with the native Maps service on Android (MapView) then you should note that this may not have the same features as the Javascript API.

Answer (score 1):

> But in Android Google API, in the native map, streetview doesn't yield any change when set to true.

It should load in a set of map tiles with blue lines on streets where there is Street View data.

> In Stack Overflow, it has been answered as a deprecated function.

`setStreetView()` is not marked as deprecated in [the JavaDocs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/index).

> Does anyone know where Google / Android has mentioned about this?

Since you declined to specify what is "this", I cannot answer that.

> Can we get panoramic picture view by using Google API 11?

`MapView` does not support "panoramic picture view" and never has. That is provided by a separate application, called Google StreetView. You can use `startActivity()` [with an appropriately-structured `Intent`](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) to bring up this application, on devices that have it installed.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/index shows streetview is not in the list of deprecated method. Regarding 'this', sorry - I will reformat the question,  Does anyone know where Google / Android has mentioned about deprecation of streetview in clear words?

Comment: @subho: "shows streetview is not in the list of deprecated method." -- correct, it is not deprecated. "Does anyone know where Google / Android has mentioned about deprecation of streetview in clear words?" -- `setStreetView()` is not deprecated.